# What is the point of using dispatch as a dependency in useEffect

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, dispatch

I see some code in a project I am working on:

```
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    // some code 
  }, [dispatch]);
```

What is the point of using `[dispatch]`? Why not just use `[]`?

Comment: I think you can find your answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59350881/useeffect-missing-dependency-when-using-redux-usedispatch

Comment: https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks